# Why has my server stopped working after trying to install SCSS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

Currently, I am following a course in React development. As a part of the course, we have to install SCSS to style an e-commerce app. So far, I have tried avoiding SCSS and reformat the code to CSS. However, since there is no $ SCSS equivalent in CSS, I am forced to install SCSS. Nevertheless, after writing

```
npm add node-sass
```

I had to restart my server and I got the error stated at the end. In the course, they mention that there might be some bugs and in that case, we should use the following lines

```
rm -rf npm.lock
rm -rf node_modules
```

Despite using these lines, my server still will not start and I am still stuck being unable to proceed since I need SCSS to work, and for that, I need my server to work because I need to restart it to install NCSS. In the following lines, I will leave the error message I get when I try to start my server. npm and node are already installed.

```
aaronserpilin@Aarons-MacBook-Air crown-clothing % npm start

> crown-clothing@0.1.0 start /Users/aaronserpilin/crown-clothing
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! crown-clothing@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the crown-clothing@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aaronserpilin/.npm/_logs/2021-10-02T13_22_23_006Z-debug.log
aaronserpilin@Aarons-MacBook-Air crown-clothing %
```

Comment: Did you run "npm install" after deleting node_modules?

Comment: Yes, but it still does not work

Comment: "react-scripts: command not found" means that react-scripts is not installed. What error you get after npm install?

Comment: I don't get any errors. Every time I write npm install it just starts installing again

Answer (score 0):

what your node-sass version used?

i used node-sass@4.14.1 and react@17.0.0 is work